# Google API Android Key issue with SHA-1 fingerprint restriction

Tags: android, google-api, google-books

The Android key works fine when I use without SHA-1 restriction. But as soon as I put restriction using package name and SHA-1 fingerprint (be it [debug key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34150985/1951418) or release key), the API stops working. The package name and SHA-1 fingerprint value is correct (with no spaces), checked hundred times.

I have seen posts of [similar issue in google product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en&nomobile=true#!topic/books-api/BlG7mufbpyg;context-place=forum/books-api) as well. [Is it something to do with this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34126044/1951418)? Anybody knows the reason or solution?

I am using Google Books API.

Comment: How are you calling the API? Are you using one of Google's client libraries?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989062/restricting-usage-for-an-android-key-for-a-google-api