# google custom search api for android

Tags: android, google-custom-search

When I am trying to run the below URL:

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=a&key=AIzaSyAlA7Vv79S_pH8tWjD-SAFUIlVh2ZzHw2o&cx=002019692856142923148:nijox13azs4

the response is:

> {"error": {"errors": [{"domain": "usageLimits","reason":
>   "ipRefererBlocked",
>       "message": "The referrer null does not match does not match the referrer restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API
>   Console to update your key restrictions.","extendedHelp":
>   "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=672025619957"}],
>   "code": 403,"message": "The referrer null does not match does not
>   match the referrer restrictions configured on your API key. Please use
>   the API Console to update your key restrictions."}}

I have generated the browser api key.. please tell me where is my mistake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: look here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989062/restricting-usage-for-an-android-key-for-a-google-api