# Error 403 with Android restricted Cloud Platform API key and Cloud Endpoints

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-java-client

I have a problem restricting a Google Cloud Platform API key usage to an Android app: I have added its package name and certificate SHA-1 fingerprint (the debug one to get started) but it doesn't work.

[image: My Cloud Platform API key panel]

The error I get when calling any API is

> 403 Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked.

I'm calling the APIs by using a Cloud Endpoints generated client lib, and I've not been able to find any method that I can use at initialisation time to set the app credentials, nor does it do it by itself (as I can guess from the "<empty>" in the error).
I can't find any useful info in any documentation as well, as far as I've red it seems like it should do it by itself.

This is my init code:

```
MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                .setApplicationName("<my package name>")
                .setRootUrl(<my root URL>)
                .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new MyApiRequestInitializer(<my API key>));
```

I've also tried what suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42851756/5219866) but nothing changed.

Is there any passage I'm missing? How should it be done?

Comment: how did you configure your Cloud Endpoints?

Comment: Same problem here!

Comment: @MichaelMeyer , I've configured them using standard Cloud Endpoints Framework 2, use only with API Key. I've followed this [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/endpoints-frameworks-v2/backend/src/main/java/com/example/echo/Echo.java), method `echoApiKey(Message message, @Named("n") @Nullable Integer n)`.

Comment: @Ultimecia did you find an answer ??

Comment: @AhmedD.Sherif unfortunately not yet...

Comment: Setting the header `httpHeaders.set("X-Android-Package", 'my.package.name');` was able to fill the _<empty>_ slot though still getting the error even though that package name is defined in api description. That's pretty weird. Appending the header _X-Android-Cert_ solves the problem but I don't think sending the signature through the header within the code adds much security. I did not think signature as something that can be achieved through the code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem appears only in emulators. I am getting the same error when running my app in an emulator. However, on real devices I do not seem to have the problem. Have you tested it on a real device?

Comment: Yes, I did that, it was a Nexus 5X (sorry for the late response, I did not see any notification).