# How do I supply Header info such as Package Name and SHA1 in Google API request?

Tags: c#, xamarin, google-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to access Google API using dotNet SDK. When I don't have API restriction, I can just access and get JSON using the following code. I can still access with IP address restriction. But when I want to use with application restriction, I have to provide Package Name and SHA-1, which I already generated.

I just don't know how to provide this header info when requesting API get.
There are several ways to implement the credentials. By using the service account, I only need to provide email and private key, but I don't want to use OAuth access. Please let me know if there is the best way to implement it.

```
var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    ApiKey = "****",
    // HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "*****"
});
```

[Similar solution but it's in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43443130)

Comment: BaseClientService allows for an IHttpClientFactory so you can provide a factory

Comment: Thanks. So is it something like this? 
`youtubeService.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Android-Package", AppInfo.PackageName);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found the right way to supply Package Name and SHA1. Now I can get the Json return correctly with app restriction.

```
youtubeService.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Android-Package", AppInfo.PackageName);
youtubeService.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Android-Cert","******");
```

**SHA-1** certificate fingerprint must be in a **lowercase string without semicolon** while sending it in an API request header.

And is there a way to get the SHA1 in code instead of simply putting it as a string? Please also let me know if there is a nicer way to code this `youtubeService.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add`

I got the clue from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49826924).

Comment: Thanks for "lowercase string without semicolon" I couldn't figure out the problem because I was just providing sha1 like copied from the .apk file

Comment: Thanks for the lowercase string without colons!

Answer (score 0):

**Xamarin and the Google APIs .net client library**

You appear to be trying to use the [Google apis .net client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client) with Xamarin.  The Google apis .net client library does not support Xamarin.

Please see issue [Investigate Xamarin support #984](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/984)

I suspect you will at very least need to code all of the authentication yourself after that you may be able to get some of the class libraries to work.   My investigation leads me to believe that the main issue with the library and Xamarin is the authorization implementation.

**Service account and YouTube**

The YouTube API does not support service account authentication you will need to use Oauth2 and authenticate your user that way.