# Google Translate API: Requests from this client application <empty> are blocked

Tags: java, android, google-translate, google-translation-api

I've been getting error 403 - Requests from this Android client application  are blocked using paid Google Cloud Platform Translation API. Works great when restrictions are set to none.
There are a few threads around reporting similar issue, but none answered.

I've seen in some examples, there's a version which had .setApplicationName(), I think that might help, but I can't find which version would that be.

Code used is:`

```
private void translate(String textToTranslate, String targetLanguage, TranslateCallback callback) {
    try {
        TranslateOptions options = TranslateOptions.newBuilder()
                        .setApiKey( < api_key >)
                        .build();
        Translate trService = options.getService();
        Translation translation = trService.translate(textToTranslate,TranslateOption.targetLanguage(targetLanguage));
        callback.onSuccess(translation.getTranslatedText());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        callback.onFailure();
    }
}`
```

from: https://medium.com/@amsanjeev/adding-translate-api-to-android-apps-788c5bca5521

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: No, I ended up using web API key, REST and setting refferer to make it look like web request. Not the prettiest, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a way.

When setting up your API key restriction for android app, you specified the package name and SHA-1 certificate fingerprint. So when you send an request to Google, you must add these information in the header of each request.

```
connection.setRequestProperty("X-Android-Package", "com.example.awesomeapp");
String sign = "5D:5A:12:D3:......".toLowerCase(); //Your SHA1 key in lower cased.
connection.setRequestProperty("X-Android-Cert", sig);
```

A detailed answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989062/restricting-usage-for-an-android-key-for-a-google-api/42851756#42851756).

Comment: That's one of possible workarounds, but still no solution for Translate API.