# Google cloud translation api

Tags: android, api, cloud, translation, google-cloud-translate

Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Requests from this Android client application  are blocked.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Requests from this Android client application  are blocked.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Translate API: Requests from this client application <empty> are blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49958986/google-translate-api-requests-from-this-client-application-empty-are-blocked)

Comment: I have already tested that article. not working for me