# How to save sensitive tokens in my flutter code

Tags: flutter

I have sensitive tokens in my flutter code. Those tokens are for example used to access my API:s and I am worried that if someone tries to hack my API they will only need to decompile my app and find the token in my flutter code.

Is there any best practice for this scenario?

Comment: NEVER STORE API KEYS IN CLIENT SIDE!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61894868/securely-saving-api-keys-in-android-flutter-apps