# Is it secure saving a private key in an ENV file for a Flutter project

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter application which communicates with an Hasura server and I'm doing it using the secret password.
I am currently using an `.env` file with the required API (secret) keys and loading them with the provided Flutter methods, but I guess they are somehow added to the app binary so I would like to know if it can be reverse engineered when published.
Does anybody know if this is a secure way to keep my API keys or I need to add authentication?

Comment: Unless you're using some sort of Zero Knowledge Proof, your app will have to have some sort of credentials.  And if it's in there, it can be reverse engineered.

Comment: What do you mean with "Zero knowledge proof"? The app is using HTTPS, I don't know if it is what do you refer.

Comment: @user18309290 Yes of course, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If an API key can't be seen don't store it in your app. For more information see [Securely Saving API Keys In Android (flutter) Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61894868/securely-saving-api-keys-in-android-flutter-apps)