# How can i protect my string (Contains Api key OpenAI) from reverse engineering flutter

Tags: android, ios, string, flutter, security

I want to publish my flutter app to the google play store, but i was thinking is my api key safe, can other people don't acces my api key and use it on my cost? So i found out that my flutter app can be reversed engineered and the api key can be stolen. How can i make it harder to let this happen? I already have the idea to obfuscate it, but is their a another way to extra protect it?

```
String apikey "ApiKey";
```

My api key is now hardcoded into the app

Comment: What is the api key for?

Comment: The api key is their to identify my app for openai. This is required. Without this i can't ask anything to the Ai of OpenAI.

Comment: Sorry should have read the title better. You can't really secure it if it is used in the app. The only true security is using it from a secure server by calling a function from the app. This link talks about your specific case though. https://help.openai.com/en/articles/5112595-best-practices-for-api-key-safety Also, if it is hardcoded in the app currently and you have saved that to GitHub, it is also potentially exposed.

Comment: Also see this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61894868/securely-saving-api-keys-in-android-flutter-apps

Comment: Do you know how i can use an key management service inside of flutter?

Comment: Seems there are a few packages....just google flutter key management

Answer (score 2):

### Your Problem

> I want to publish my flutter app to the google play store, but i was thinking is my api key safe, can other people don't acces my api key and use it on my cost?

Not it's not safe at all, anyone can access it. It's as easy as using static analysis,a MitM attack and/or instrumentation at runtime. Let's see how...

### Reverse Engineering a Mobile App

> So i found out that my flutter app can be reversed engineered and the api key can be stolen.

In a series of articles on Mobile and API Secuirty I wrote you can read the article
[How to Extract an API key from a Mobile App with Static Binary Analysis](https://blog.approov.io/how-to-extract-an-api-key-from-a-mobile-app-with-static-binary-analysis) to see how easy it's to extract your `ApiKey`:

> The range of open source tools available for reverse engineering is huge, and we really can't scratch the surface of this topic in this article, but instead we will focus in using the [Mobile Security Framework(MobSF)](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF) to demonstrate how to reverse engineer the APK of our mobile app. MobSF is a collection of open source tools that present their results in an attractive dashboard, but the same tools used under the hood within MobSF and elsewhere can be used individually to achieve the same results.
>
> During this article we will use the [Android Hide Secrets](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF) research repository that is a dummy mobile app with API keys hidden using several different techniques.

#### For Mobile apps using code obfuscation

> I already have the idea to obfuscate it

If you use obfuscation it will make more difficult to find it with static analysis, but that's not an issue for an attacker once it's very easy to extract your Api Key at runtime with MitM attack, and you can read about how its done in my article [Steal that Api Key with a Man in the Middle Attack](https://blog.approov.io/steal-that-api-key-with-a-man-in-the-middle-attack):

> In order to help to demonstrate how to steal an API key, I have built and released in Github the [Currency Converter Demo](https://github.com/approov/currency-converter-demo/tree/0.1.1) app for Android, which uses the same [JNI/NDK](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni) technique we used in the earlier [Android Hide Secrets](https://github.com/approov/android-hide-secrets/blob/ed0217325d42be480a15c003fae9f201ee0f3f88/app/src/main/java/com/criticalblue/androidhidesecrets/MainActivity.java#L37-L41) app to [hide the API key](https://github.com/approov/android-hide-secrets/blob/ed0217325d42be480a15c003fae9f201ee0f3f88/app/src/main/cpp/api_key.h.example).
>
> So, in this article you will learn how to setup and run a MitM attack to intercept https traffic in a mobile device under your control, so that you can steal the API key. Finally, you will see at a high level how MitM attacks can be mitigated.

#### For mobile apps using certificate pinning

You have not mention its use, but its a common and recommend layer of defence to prevent a MitM attack, at least will keep at bay the less skilled attackers, but unfortunately it can be bypassed with the use of an instrumentation framework during runtime, and guess what, you can read on how to do it on my article [How to Bypass Certificate Pinning with Frida on an Android App](https://blog.approov.io/how-to-bypass-certificate-pinning-with-frida-on-an-android-app) to show you how to do it:

> Today I will show how to use the Frida instrumentation framework to hook into the mobile app at runtime and instrument the code in order to perform a successful MitM attack even when the mobile app has implemented certificate pinning.

> Bypassing certificate pinning is not too hard, just a little laborious, and allows an attacker to understand in detail how a mobile app communicates with its API, and then use that same knowledge to automate attacks or build other services around it.

Despite it can be bypassed its still recommend to use certificate pinning.

### Possible Solution

> How can i make it harder to let this happen? I already have the idea to obfuscate it, but is their a another way to extra protect it?

Obfuscation its only effective to protect intellectual property of your code, but will only hide your secret at rest on the code, not when the app is running.

I will recommend you to read [my accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75109966/6454622) to the question *How to use an API from my mobile app without someone stealing the token* where the Runtime Secrets Protection seems to be an approach suitable to your use case.

In a nutshell you will have the secret stored in the cloud and have it securely delivered just-in-time of being used to your mobile app, but only if the same is not being under attack, running on a root or jail broken device, isn't attached to a debugger or running in an emulator.

### Do You Want To Go The Extra Mile?

In any response to a security question I always like to reference the excellent work from the OWASP foundation.

#### For APIS

[OWASP API Security Top 10](https://github.com/OWASP/API-Security)

> The OWASP API Security Project seeks to provide value to software developers and security assessors by underscoring the potential risks in insecure APIs, and illustrating how these risks may be mitigated. In order to facilitate this goal, the OWASP API Security Project will create and maintain a Top 10 API Security Risks document, as well as a documentation portal for best practices when creating or assessing APIs.

#### For Mobile Apps

[OWASP Mobile Security Project - Top 10 risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project#Top_Ten_Mobile_Risks)

> The OWASP Mobile Security Project is a centralized resource intended to give developers and security teams the resources they need to build and maintain secure mobile applications. Through the project, our goal is to classify mobile security risks and provide developmental controls to reduce their impact or likelihood of exploitation.

[OWASP - Mobile Security Testing Guide](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg):

> The Mobile Security Testing Guide (MSTG) is a comprehensive manual for mobile app security development, testing and reverse engineering.