# How to convert googleapis/java-translate library to custom api rest request using google translation api v3 in an Android project

Tags: android, api, rest, kotlin, google-translation-api

Before seeing conflicts when building a release for my app because of [googleapis/java-translate](https://github.com/googleapis/java-translate) library, I used these lines and it worked perfectly :

```kotlin
    val translate: Translate = TranslateOptions.newBuilder().setApiKey(API_KEY).build().service
    val translations = translate.translate(
         textsToTranslate,
         Translate.TranslateOption.sourceLanguage(sourceLanguage),
         Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage(targetLanguage)
    )
```

Then, when building release, I had to add some extra code in app/build.gradle to make it works.
But, I saw that my app grows from 10Mo to 15Mo. Expensive just for translating some texts..

So I decide to perform these translations by myself using the latest Google Translate Api v3
[link](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects/translateText)

Perform a simple api rest request like this :

```kotlin
    val jsonObjectResponse = JSONObject(translate(sourceLanguageCode = sourceLanguage, targetLanguageCode = targetLanguage, textsToTranslate).awaitString())
    val translations = jsonObjectResponse.getJSONArray("translations").toArray { getJSONObject(it) }.map { it.getString("translatedText") }
```

where "translate" function is :

```kotlin
    private fun translate(sourceLanguageCode: String, targetLanguageCode: String, textsToTranslate: List<String>): Request =
        Fuel.post(path = "https://translation.googleapis.com/v3/projects/$PROJECT_ID:translateText?key=$API_KEY")
            .header(Headers.ACCEPT to "application/json")
            .jsonBody(
                JSONObject().apply {
                    put("contents", JSONArray().apply {
                        textsToTranslate.forEach { text -> put(text) }
                    })
                    put("sourceLanguageCode", sourceLanguageCode)
                    put("targetLanguageCode", targetLanguageCode)
                }.toString()
            )
```

but it returns : "HTTP Exception 401 Unautorhorized". The link doesn't mention usage of API_KEY so I suppose it's related to..

Note : [Fuel](https://github.com/kittinunf/fuel) is just a HTTP networking library for Kotlin/Android to avoid boiler plate code.

To resume: the first one using googleapis/java-translate was working but the second (custom) doesn't work and returns : "HTTP Exception 401 Unautorhorized".

**Where am I wrong ?**

*Extra note: I know I'm not restricting right now to the package name of the android app but here, I just want to make it works :)*

**Edit**

- jsonBody function add implicitly header "Content-Type" to "application/json"
- If apiKey can't be use in v3, which other way can I use ? I already have firebase Crashlytics, it means I already have a google service to potentially handle a communication to a google service but there's way too much documentation going all over the place, it's just terrible, it makes me sick. Which library can I use to handle credential in android application without breaking my app for "Meta-*** conflict", etc. I'm confused and lost in this ocean of information.

**Edit - 03 december 2020**

Goodbye bounty [400]

Ended up using Google Translate API v2 with REST :

```kotlin
// portion of suspend function code
coroutineScope {
        async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                //handleTranslateV3Response(requests, JSONObject(translateV3(sourceLanguageCode = sourceLanguage, targetLanguageCode = targetLanguage, textsToTranslate = textsToTranslate).awaitString()))
                //handleTranslateV2Response(requests, JSONObject(translateV2RestrictedToApplication(targetLanguageCode = targetLanguage, textsToTranslate = textsToTranslate, signature = signature).awaitString()))
                handleTranslateV2Response(requests, JSONObject(translateV2(targetLanguageCode = targetLanguage, textsToTranslate = textsToTranslate).awaitString()))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Timber.tag("Translate").e(e)
                val message: String = "An error occurred while translating ${sourceLanguage} to ${targetLanguage}"
                requests.mapIndexed { index, entityTranslationRequest ->
                    TranslationResponse.Error(message, entityTranslationRequest)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```kotlin
    /**
     * Usage of Google Translate API v2 without restriction
     * This function works properly
     */
    private fun translateV2(targetLanguageCode: String, textsToTranslate: List<String>): Request =
        Fuel.post(path = "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=$API_KEY")
            .header(Headers.ACCEPT to "application/json")
            .jsonBody(
                JSONObject().apply {
                    put("q", JSONArray().apply {
                        textsToTranslate.forEach { text -> put(text) }
                    })
                    put("target", targetLanguageCode)
                }.toString()
            )
            .header(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE to "application/json; charset=utf-8")

    private fun handleTranslateV2Response(requests: List<EntityTranslationRequest>, jsonObject: JSONObject): List<TranslationResponse> {
        val translations = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("translations").toArray { getJSONObject(it) }.map { it.getString("translatedText") }

        return requests.mapIndexed { index, entityTranslationRequest ->
            TranslationResponse.Success(translations[index], entityTranslationRequest)
        }
    }
```

When using Android application restriction on this API KEY, the code below don't work.
According to [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42851756/4566621) and [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34126044/4566621) and [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58041000/4566621) from the same issue.
There is no proper way to send fingerprints by ourselves without using one of multiple google libraries which handles Auth2, credentials, etc...

```kotlin
    /**
     * Usage of Google Translate API v2 with restriction to android app
     * This function doesn't work and returns a "HTTP Exception 403 Forbidden"
     * @param signature SHA-1
     */
    private fun translateV2RestrictedToApplication(signature: String, targetLanguageCode: String, textsToTranslate: List<String>): Request =
        Fuel.post(path = "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=$API_KEY")
            .header(Headers.ACCEPT to "application/json")
            .header("X-Android-Package" to BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)
            .header("X-Android-Cert" to signature.toLowerCase())
            .jsonBody(
                JSONObject().apply {
                    put("q", JSONArray().apply {
                        textsToTranslate.forEach { text -> put(text) }
                    })
                    put("target", targetLanguageCode)
                }.toString()
            )
            .header(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE to "application/json; charset=utf-8")
```

Below is the code for the v3 which don't work because it requires token which seems to be generate only from Google libraries and I'm tired of documentation splitted everywhere, makes me sick.

```kotlin
    /**
     * Usage of Google Translate API v3
     * This function doesn't work and returns a "HTTP Exception 401 Unautorhorized"
     */
    private fun translateV3(sourceLanguageCode: String, targetLanguageCode: String, textsToTranslate: List<String>): Request =
        Fuel.post(path = "https://translation.googleapis.com/v3/projects/$PROJECT_ID:translateText")
            .header(Headers.ACCEPT to "application/json")
            .header(Headers.AUTHORIZATION to "Bearer {token provided by some Google libraries I guess}")
            .jsonBody(
                JSONObject().apply {
                    put("contents", JSONArray().apply {
                        textsToTranslate.forEach { text -> put(text) }
                    })
                    put("sourceLanguageCode", sourceLanguageCode)
                    put("targetLanguageCode", targetLanguageCode)
                }.toString()
            )
            .header(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE to "application/json; charset=utf-8")

    private fun handleTranslateV3Response(requests: List<EntityTranslationRequest>, jsonObject: JSONObject): List<TranslationResponse> {
        val translations = jsonObject.getJSONArray("translations").toArray { getJSONObject(it) }.map { it.getString("translatedText") }

        return requests.mapIndexed { index, entityTranslationRequest ->
            TranslationResponse.Success(translations[index], entityTranslationRequest)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same error from IBM Watson Translator and solved it yet
so I thought the error are coming

1. content type request: which must be specified like "Content-Type":"application/json"
2. authorization: I am not sure with you but most of the time authorization key(api key)
   must be specified in the header request
3. API KEY: it depends on the api key most of the time if api key have space between words it may not work

I have got [this](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translating-text-v3) tutorial as the easiest way to do it tho in v3.
and to start the you need the authorization and content type request from the header, you need to do like

```
//okhttp3 library used
fun doRequest(){
            val json = """${data("en","fr","Hello World")}"""
            val request = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), json);
            val response = Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://translation.googleapis.com/v3/projects/project-number-or-id/locations/us-central1:translateText")
                    .post(request)
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer YOUR_API_GOES_HERE")
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                    .build()
            val answer = client.newCall(response).execute().body()!!.string()
print(answer)
}
```

**WARNING**: if the API_KEY have space like "apikey SFKHNKSJH-CSDFSCU" you need to convert it to single key using [this](https://www.blitter.se/utils/basic-authentication-header-generator) kind of tool

```
fun data(fromLang: String, toLang: String, word: String): String{
      return """{
  "sourceLanguageCode": "${fromLang}",
  "targetLanguageCodes": "${toLang}",
  "contents": ["${word}"]
}"""

}
```

[These](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/) docs might help you.

Comment: 1. the jsonBody add implicitly the header "Content-Type" to "application/json". I also tried with "charset=utf-8".
2. In the documentation, in the curl example, they use "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)
Their doc don't mention any usage of API KEY or something like that but I don't have any other information than this one and I try with it but it did not work.
3. No space in their API KEY.

The problem is probably related to authorization bearer part but no good information about that.

Comment: What drives me crazy is that I just have to mention their API KEY with their library and it works. So unless they hack their own APIs to get around the 401 error, I don't see why a simple request couldn't work.

Comment: @sokarcreative try the request with curl or *.http file from idea ultimate and if it works that would be error from your code or if not post the error here .that would show as the detail