# How to Restrict calling api only apps installed from AppStore using swift

Tags: ios, swift

**I read this information below link:**
[Restricting usage for an Android key for a Google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989062/restricting-usage-for-an-android-key-for-a-google-api/42851756#42851756)

So My question is about I have php project as a backend my project has API calling from mobile app like android and iOS. I got it how to restrict calling API android app downloaded only from play store so How can I implement this idea in my swift project to Restrict calling my api only apps that installed from AppStore. How do i know if installed from app store or not in my iphone, I need to call my API only apps from Appstore.

**Can any one help me?**

Comment: From iOS 14 on you can use App Attestation in the device check framework. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/validating_apps_that_connect_to_your_server

Comment: How many app stores for iOS out there?  And to which app store is your app distributed?