# Places SDK for Android: API key restriction causing "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key" error

Tags: android, api-key, android-security, google-places-autocomplete, google-api-key-restrictions

I am using the "Places Autocomplete" feature of the Places SDK for Android. I have set up an API key via the Google Cloud credentials console, and it worked great.

However, I attempted restricting my API key usage to my specific app, and it no longer works. In logcat, I can see

*This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address xx with empty referer*

I am sure I've entered by package name and SHA-1 fingerprint correctly on the API key restriction page.

I've seen lots of similar questions. Some answers involved setting up a "server" API key instead of an "Android" API key, but I *think* that's no longer relevant. Other answers claim that the Places API can only be restricted via IP addresses. But surely that can't be right-- how is this supposed to work???

Any ideas or clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for this? :(

Comment: No, I did not. I decided to abandon using the API, in part for this reason, but also because it's quite expensive and I realized that just maintaining my own database of US cities wasn't too hard. (Obviously, that won't work for all use cases.) Sorry!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, it's pretty expensive to use. However, for me, this was the only option, and had to find a solution. my solution was adding a  SHA-1 fingerprint from the Google Play console. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65700246/4517005